# Why get null empty varchar record and 0 as date record when using Java insert value into mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

I tried insert a roll using Java from eclipse to MySQL. I got not error notification. However, when I select record from table, I got empty records in varchar type column and 0000-00-00 in date type column.

Here are code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Database {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        try{
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees";
            String user = "DDD";
            String pwd = "123456";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employees");
            PreparedStatement ps = null;

            AddEmployees newAddEmployees = new AddEmployees("555-55-5555", "DDD", "LLL", "1990-1-1", "programmerEmployee", "DEVELOP");
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(newAddEmployees.Insert());
            ps.executeUpdate();

            while (rs.next()){
                String socialSecurityNumber = rs.getString("socialSecurityNumber");
                String firstName = rs.getString("firstName");
                String lastName = rs.getString("lastName");
                String birthday = rs.getString("birthday");
                String employeeType = rs.getString("employeeType");
            String departmentName = rs.getString("departmentName");
                System.out.println(socialSecurityNumber + ", " + firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + birthday + ", " + employeeType + ", " + departmentName);
            }

            rs.close();
            conn.close();
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
       }
    }
}
```

Here are other code in the AddEmployees class:

```
public class AddEmployees extends Employees{

public AddEmployees(String socialSecurityNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String birthday,
        String employeeType, String departmentName) {
    this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.employeeType = employeeType;
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

@Override
public String Insert() {
    return SQLStatement = "insert into employees(socialSecurityNumber, firstName, lastName, birthday, employeeType, departmentName)"
            + "values (+socialSecurityNumber, +firstName, +lastName, +birthday, +employeeType, +departmentName)";
}
```

}

Here is what I got in MySQL:

```
mysql> select * from employees;
    +----------------------+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------+
    | socialSecurityNumber | firstName | lastName | birthday   | employeeType               | departmentName |
    +----------------------+-----------+----------+------------+----------------------------+----------------+
    |                      |           |          | 0000-00-00 |                            |                |
    | 111-11-1111          | John      | Smith    | 1945-01-02 | salariedEmployee           | R&D            |
    | 222-22-2222          | Sue       | Jones    | 1961-02-03 | commissionEmployee         | SALES          |
    | 333-33-3333          | Bob       | Lowis    | 1958-10-05 | basePlusCommissionEmployee | SALES          |
    | 444-44-4444          | Karen     | Price    | 1972-05-25 | hourlyEmployee             | HR             |
    +----------------------+-----------+----------+------------+-------------------

---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Insert()` method returns the literal string

```
insert into employees(socialSecurityNumber, firstName, lastName, birthday, employeeType, departmentName)
values (+socialSecurityNumber, +firstName, +lastName, +birthday, +employeeType, +departmentName)
```

You probably ment to insert your parameters instead of `+socialSecurityNumber`, `+firstName`, ... - but what you return is just a static String. Because your values are valid column names of your table, you don't get an error, and what will be inserted are the default values for the columns.

You shouln't try to use string replacement to create an SQL query anyway, that only leads to sql injection vulnerabilities in your code.

This is how [`PreparedStatement`s are intended to be used](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into employees(socialSecurityNumber, firstName, lastName, birthday, employeeType, departmentName) "
    + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
ps.setInt(1, socialSecurityNumber);
ps.setString(2, firstName);
...
ps.executeUpdate();
```